# Top sites in Network Profile in iOS app aren't top sites

Tags: bug, ios-app, network-profile

I was looking at my Network Profile in the Stack Exchange iOS app, and noticed something peculiar in the top sites: they're not my top sites. The first one, shown with profile text and top posts, is always the 'currently active' site, and then come the two (remaining) accounts with the highest reputation. At least for a dozen other profiles I've checked; [my case](https://stackexchange.com/users/6085540/glorfindel?tab=accounts) is rather ... ahem ... *puzzling*, since my Puzzling reputation (16.7k) is higher than my Chess reputation (14.2k), but it's still Chess that's showing up (left). Curiously, the Android app (right) does show the correct top sites, so it's not an API issue. Once I click the 'All 176 sites', the accounts *are* shown in order of descending reputation.

[image]
[image]

Comment: This should be tagged wont-fix as app development is frozen :)

Comment: Indeed. Should this be closed as no longer reproducible? (I have no idea whether it is actually still reproducible by those who downloaded the app before it was discontinued...)

Comment: @V2Blast I can still reproduce it - but you're right, it can be closed.